# Symfony2 - Warning: session_regenerate_id() - PHP 5.3

Tags: symfony, session, authentication, php-5.3

I got this error :

```
Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent
```

She appeared first time in file `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php at line 206` and when i refresh the page the error appear in file `app/cache/dev/classes.php at line 153`

This error appear when i try to log in my application with PHP 5.3. When the action is `http://localhost/myapp/web/app_dev.php/login_check`, so when the form is validated. I used web service to log in my app, so i created a personalized Userprovider.

When I execute my code with php 5.5 it works and i ain't got any error. So, do i need to add a special code to execute session correctly with 5.3 ?

I will edit my question if you need some code.

EDIT : i use Symfony 2.6.4

Thanks

Comment: You sure you have properly enabled error reporting on 5.5?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. i used Wamp with version 5.3 and 5.5 of PHP and it works with 5.5 :/